# Error con header(location)

Tags: php

tengo el siguiente codigo

```
<?php                         
    if(!$_GET){
      header('Location:blog.php?pagina=1');
    }                            
  ?>
```

y me da el siguiente error:

> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by
>   (output started at C:\xampp\htdocs\gp\includes\header2.php:1) in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\gp\blog.php on line 108

y en el archivo header2.php
tengo el siguiente codigo

```
<header class="header-two">
    <div class="topbar-area topbar-area-2 fix hidden-xs">
        <div class="container">
            ...
         </div>
    </div>
</header>
```

Comment: Posiblemente estás escapando a una salida HTML antes de invocar al header de PHP. Mira esta respuesta https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/how-to-fix-headers-already-sent-error-in-php

Comment: En el código html que muestras estás cerrado la etiqueta **header usando head** y header != head prueba a corregir ese detalle

Comment: Fue error mio al escribir la pregunta, en el codigo lo tengo con </header>

Comment: donde esta eso que mencionas @quevedo, eso no afecta

Comment: @Alfredo Ya lo corrigio!

Comment: el detalle es que las funciones como header() que modifican las cabeceras son código que de sebe enviar al inicio del código

Comment: Ah que caray, eso era, Gracias Alfredo!

Answer (score 1):

Prueba usar buffer

```
<?php
  ob_start();
     if(!$_GET){
        header('Location:blog.php?pagina=1');
     }    
  ob_end_flush();
?>
```

esto es suponiendo que tu script php consta nada más de lo que colocaste

Comment: No veo ningún cambio al aplicarlo :S

Comment: Trata de proporcionar más código en tu pregunta. También trata de colocar el start al principio de header2.php y el flush al final del header2.php